# Delegate vs if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, delegates

I have a class:

```
public class MyClass: IMyInterface
{

   int _parameter;
   public Myclass(int parameter)
   {
       _parameter = parameter;
       //Do other things
   }

   public int FrequentlyCalledFunction()
     {
        if(_parameter == 0)
         {
              return 0;
         }
         else
         {
           int result;
           //Do some calculations
           return result;
         }
     }

}
```

Since the _parameter is assigned once in the constructor, entering the if statement every time the FrequentlyCalledFunction is called  seems somewhat inefficient for an already created instance . 
Thus, I thought to modify the code as follows. Declare a delegate

```
public delegate int MyDlg();

public class MyClass: IMyInterface
{

   int _parameter;
   MyDlg _intermediate; 
   public Myclass(int parameter)
   {
       _parameter = parameter;
      _intermediate = _parameter == 0 ? _returnZero : _calculateAndReturn;

       //Do other things
   }


    public int FrequentlyCalledFunction()
    {
       return _intermediate();
    }

    int _returnZero()
    {
       return 0;  
    }  
    int _calculateAndReturn()
    {
         int result;
         //Do some calculations
         return result;             
    }

}
```

So now, the check will be performed only once at the moment of creating the instance. On the other hand the if statement is replaced with an additional delegate call.

The question is, assuming that the performance is very important, which approach is better?

P.S.
The FrequentlyCalledFunction is a method from the interface IMyInterface, thus, I cannot define a MyDlg FrequentlyCalledFunction and call it from the outside of the class.

Comment: First option is more readable.

Comment: If it is very frequent, the delegate would impose a performance penalty, else whatever you find elegant.

Comment: Assuming the performance is very important, don't make guesses, measure which approach is best. If the impact is too small to measure, then performance wasn't very important after all.

Comment: TEST IT.  If performance is important then spend the time to collect the metrics.

Comment: This is micro bench-marking to the bone. Run both, measure, apply readability factor and decide.

Comment: You should make the field `readonly` "since the `_parameter` is assigned once in the constructor" (your words).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking about it too much.  The best way to improve performance in this case is to make MyClass abstract, and to define two subclasses: MyClassWithCalculations and MyClassWithoutCalculations.
When you are about to create an instance of MyClass, check the parameter: if it is zero, instantiate MyClassWithoutCalculations.  If it is non-zero, instantiate MyClassWithCalculations.  No delegates, no ifs, no convoluted stuff.

That having been said, let me also add that you are probably wrong in thinking that an innocent `if( variable == 0 )` statement can affect performance in any significant way whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks. 
It can affect performance if 7 of 10 instances have that parameter set to 0 and the function is called a million times per instance.

Comment: The `if` statement represents 1 or 2 clock cycles, so on a 1 to 2 gigahertz CPU over a million invocations this will waste a grand total of about 1 millisecond.  Anyway, you know your usage scenario.

Comment: Performance will never be a factor in any of these situations. Resolving a `virtual` method call may take as long the `if` statement, I do not know.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes, a virtual method call will generally be more expensive than an `if` statement, and the delegate would only make matters worse, since it is in turn one more virtual method call.  My answer makes sense because the cost of one virtual method call cannot be avoided in the case at hand, since the OP said that `FrequentlyCalledFunction` is part of the `IMyInterface` interface.  So, there will always be one virtual method call.  The point is to do as little as possible within that call.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question trying whilst searching for ideas to improve the performance in an existing app. The scenario:

- Stream of updates that arrive at a rate of 44 Hz (every ~23ms)
- Updates are only 16 bytes of data
- What happens to the update (how it should be transformed before being output to a consuming system) depends on the value of a `Guid.`
- That `Guid`...

  - Changes *relatively* infrequently -- not for 8 hours, then a couple of times over 10 minutes.
  - Changes as a result of a call from a separate system.

The objective was to reduce the time between receiving an update and posting a value out to a consuming system.

In my scenario, an `if` statement checking the `Guid` on every update vs a `delegate` being used to point to another function **had cost of 4ms**. For us, it was worth swapping out as all our other optimisations were sub 1ms.

I guess the real answer is "test, test, test", but I thought I'd share my experience.